# Why does LogicalTreeHelper does not return the columns as children of the DataGrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"
          x:Name="grdMyGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 3" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

' I use this for the translation stuff
LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(grdMyGrid)
```

Why does [LogicalTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.aspx) does not return the columns as children of the DataGrid?

I do a generic function for all the WPF control. the grid is a small part of it. All the items are translated, but not the grid columns, because the recursive translation function that uses the code `LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(myFrameworkElement)` does not pass inside the grid.

What to do?

Comment: The DataGrid's children are the items in the DataGrid. And beside that the  DataGrid's Columns are not part of the logical tree.  But if you have a reference to `grdMyGrid` why don't you access its columns with `grdMyGrid.Columns`?

Comment: I do a generic function for all the WPF control. the grid is a small part of it. All the items are translated, but not the grid columns.